# When outputting with mpdf, there are cases where letters overlap and protrude into another cell.

Tags: php, mpdf

When outputting with mpdf, there are cases where letters overlap and protrude into another cell. When trying with the same number of characters, there was no problem with other character strings. I also tried the number of characters before and after the problematic characters, but it did not matter. It seems to have occurred in a specific string. Please tell me what this is the problem.

Comment: Which cases? What "other character strings"? Please include an example of your code.

Comment: The code can not be described in detail due to various circumstances, also about words.
I'm sorry.

Comment: How does mpdf perform automatic line feed of character strings?